# Dynamic arguments

Tags: php, oop, laravel-5, type-hinting

Im using Laravel 5.2 and I'd like to create a method where the argument must be an instance of either Foo, Bar, or Baz. If the argument is not an object of any of those classes, throw an error.

```
App\Models\Foo;
App\Models\Bar;
App\Models\Baz;


public function someMethod(// what to type hint here??)
{
   // if 1st argument passed to someMethod() is not an object of either class Foo, Bar, Baz then throw an error
}
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use both class name and interface for type hinting, but only if all 3 classes extend the same class or implement the same interface, otherwise you will not be able to do so:

```
class C {}
class D extends C {}

function f(C $c) {
    echo get_class($c)."\n";
}

f(new C);
f(new D);
```

This will work also for interfaces:

```
interface I { public function f(); }
class C implements I { public function f() {} }

function f(I $i) {
    echo get_class($i)."\n";
}

f(new C);
```

Comment: Considering that you can implement multiple interfaces, i believe best practise is to implement an interface like Dekel has demonstrated.

Comment: @Nitin structuring your classes based on the input requirements of a single method is far from best practice. There are plenty of instances where this method will be suitable, of course.

Comment: Excellent use of interfaces, I like it.

Comment: @rjdown good point. In that case, your solution is the right option if the method is limited to a single use. Otherwise there is a chance of duplicating the control structure. +1 for your answer as well, i will use this too.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to provide multiple type hints in the way that you want (except if they extend/implement each other as per Dekel's answer).

You will need to enforce the type manually, for example:

```
public function someMethod($object) {
    if (!in_array(get_class($object), array('Foo', 'Bar', 'Baz'))) {
        throw new Exception('ARGGH');
    }
}
```

You can help the end user somewhat by providing the list of required types as a phpdoc hint:

```
/**
 * Does some stuff
 * 
 * @param Foo|Bar|Baz $object
 * @throws Exception
 */
```

Comment: Likewise, all helpful stuff

Answer (score 1):

"Multiple" typehinting is not supported.

Simple solution is check with `instanceof` (or @rjdown solution)

```
public function someMethod($arg) 
{
    if (!$arg instanceof Foo && !$arg instanceof Bar && !$arg instanceof Bar) {
        throw new \Exception("Text here")  
    }
}
```

Or make all you classes `implement` some `interface`. For example:

```
class Foo implements SomeInterface;
class Bar implements SomeInterface;
class Baz implements SomeInterface;

// then you can typehint:
public function someMethod(SomeInterface $arg)
```